Sentencia SQL para seleccionar valores que deben cumplir con N criterios
Desde ya agradecer de vuestra ayuda y perdón las preguntas dado que estoy iniciando en SQL.
Contexto: Estamos realizando un proyecto donde se deben revisar roles asociados al sistema SAP. El tema es que la estructura de las tablas y datos, vienen directamente del sistema, donde principalmente estoy trabajando con 4 tablas

AGR_1251 = Tabla que almacena el detalle de todos los roles y su configuración en el sistema
AGR_USERS = Tabla que almacena entre otras cosas, el usuario y el rol actualmente asignado
USR02 = Tabla que almacena la información de usuario y entre algunas cosas datos como lastlogon, quien lo creo, etc
Usuario_nombres = Tabla creada por mi para almacenar ID + nombre completo de las personas (contiene dos columnas: Usuario y nombre)
U_Type = Tabla creada por mi para almacenar la nomenclatura y el tipo de usuario (contiene dos campos: ID y tipo)

El problema que tengo es que necesito hacer consultas especificas que en muchas ocasiones se debe hacer un filtro sobre una misma columna con distintos valores y todos ellos deben cumplirse, es decir es un operador "Y", por ejemplo:
Columna1 = Objeto1 Y Objeto 2 Y Objeto3, etc
El tema esta es que cuando genero mi consulta y utilizo la siguiente sentencia (el siguiente es un ejemplo):
SELECT * FROM AGR_1251 WHERE A.LOW IN ('SCC4', '02', 'SS', 'TABL') 
AND  A.FIELD IN ('TCD', 'ACTVT', 'DICBERCLS', 'CTS_ADMFCT')  
AND A.OBJECT IN ('S_TCODE', 'S_TABU_DIS', 'S_CTS_ADMI');

Si bien me trae datos, muchos son falsos positivos dado que puede ocurrir que un rol puede contener al menos uno de estos valores, ya lo considera valido para el SELECT. Yo necesito que cumplan TODOS sus valores, no que cumpla a lo menos uno. Como dato adicional:

A.LOW = es una columna que guarda el valor que tiene un campo de un objeto
A.FIELD = es la columna que indica el tipo de campo que se esta
seleccionando en el rol para ser modificado y que afectara (en la UI
de SAP) los botones u opciones que el usuario tendrá
A.OBJECT = es la
columna que almacena el nombre del objeto padre que controla las
acciones del usuario dentro del sistema.

Las tres columnas deben cumplirse para que la combinatoria se denomine como "riesgosa" y que es objetivo del proyecto.
¿Que debo modificar en la sentencia SQL para lograr quitar falsos positivos y solo dejar aquellos roles que cumplan con la combinatoria obligatoria? Como ejemplo dejo la combinacion que necesito exigir a la tabla:

Pido disculpas desde ya, es bastante complejo para mi poder explicar el problema.

Si estas iniciando en SQL, lo mejor que te puedo decir es que vayas por partes.. lo primero que tenes que hacer, es ubicar todos los registros que cumplan tu primera fila (s_tcode,tcd,scc4).. una vez que haces eso, a esa query le aplicas el siguiente filtro, y asi seguis.. lo que vos queres hacer, se podria hacer en una sola query... pero es una query espantosa... y no, no se hace asi como lo estas intentando...

lo que puedes ir haciendo es anidar las consultas por ej:
select * from (select * from tabla t where t.campo = condicion_1) ts
where ts.campo2 = condicion_2
así puedes ir filtrando los campos de una forma más controlada lo permite que no tengas falsos positivos
